# Sizing of UITableView - not sure what is going on and scrolling always snaps back to top

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am not a full-time iOS dev so this might be really simple. I have a UITableView that is a property called menuTV. However, it doesn't scroll property - essentially, the size doesn't reflect the size of the content. It basically just snaps back to the starting point. I have

```
  [self.menuTV reloadData];
  self.menuTV.scrollEnabled=YES;
  self.menuTV.separatorColor = [UIColor clearColor];
  self.menuTV.delegate=self;
  self.menuTV.dataSource=self;
  //self.menuTV.frame.size=CGSizeMake(320.0, 3500.0f);
  [self.menuTV layoutIfNeeded];
  CGSize tableSize = [self.menuTV sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(320.0f, 5000.0f)];
  self.menuTV.frame=CGRectMake(0.0f, 64.0f, 320.0f, tableSize.height);

  [self.view addSubview:self.menuTV];
  
  NSLog(@" self.menuTV contentSize.height: %f", self.menuTV.contentSize.height);
  NSLog(@" self.menuTV frame.size.height: %f", self.menuTV.frame.size.height);
```

In the log, I get:

```
  014-08-19 14:51:20.768 ios[44563:60b]  self.menuTV contentSize.height: 1217.080078
  2014-08-19 14:51:20.768 ios[44563:60b]  self.menuTV frame.size.height: 1217.080078
```

I am not sure what the next step is; it looks like the frame is being set to a large size but it just snaps back to the top. How would I make it so that it scrolls to reflect true size of the UITableView?

### Edit #1

I updated the code:

```
  NSLog(@"before self.menuTV contentSize.height: %f", self.menuTV.contentSize.height);
  NSLog(@"before self.menuTV frame.size.height: %f", self.menuTV.frame.size.height);
  CGSize tableSize = [self.menuTV sizeThatFits:CGSizeMake(320.0f, 5000.0f)];
  self.menuTV.frame=CGRectMake(0.0f, 64.0f, 320.0f, tableSize.height);
  [self.view addSubview:self.menuTV];
  
  NSLog(@" self.menuTV contentSize.height: %f", self.menuTV.contentSize.height);
  NSLog(@" self.menuTV frame.size.height: %f", self.menuTV.frame.size.height);
```

Log:

```
2014-08-19 15:11:22.304 lucques-ios[44708:60b] before self.menuTV contentSize.height: 1407.120117
2014-08-19 15:11:22.304 lucques-ios[44708:60b] before self.menuTV frame.size.height: 480.000000
2014-08-19 15:11:22.305 lucques-ios[44708:60b]  self.menuTV contentSize.height: 1407.120117
2014-08-19 15:11:22.305 lucques-ios[44708:60b]  self.menuTV frame.size.height: 1407.120117
```

### Edit 2

It was a trivial cause - I configured diff in both storyboard and code.

Comment: What is the value before the `sizeThatFits:`?  I have a feeling this an auto-layout problem.

Comment: I updated the question with the ouput in edit #1. Also, the UITableView is created in a Storyboard but have provided the above configuration. For 'View' -> 'Mode', it is set to 'Scale To Fill' - don't think that would be affecting but checkign right now

Comment: it's hard to tell what is being controlled by your storyboard and what is being done programmatically. You say that you're setting a tableView in the storyboard, so you shouldn't need to set self.menuTV.frame, nor add it to self.view. Tableviews are also complex in that their frame is different from their contentSize, and I'm not sure if you're just trying to make the frame of the tableView fill the screen, or actually make it 5000 pixels long, which should probably be your contentSize instead.

Comment: thx for feedback = I think you're right ^^ and just started over

Comment: Given the answer, this can be closed as "Not reproducible or was caused by a typo".